# Bootstrap + jQuery validationEngine make custom ajax validation call onFieldSuccess to update feedback

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

I am using the [jQuery Validation Engine](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/) plugin to validate my form. I am also using Bootstrap to give the user feedback (success/fail) of the given input.

Here is how I am initializing the plugin:

**jquery**

```
$.validationEngine.defaults.promptPosition = 'inline';

$.validationEngine.defaults.onFieldFailure = function (field) {
    console.log('onFieldFailure called');

    field.parent().removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    field.nextAll('span').children().removeClass('fa-check').addClass('fa-remove');
};

$.validationEngine.defaults.onFieldSuccess = function (field) {
    console.log('onFieldSuccess called');

    field.parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    field.nextAll('span').children().removeClass('fa-remove').addClass('fa-check');
};

$form.validationEngine('attach');
```

I am using CodeIgniter to handle the form server-side. Everything is working great.

**html/php**

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="email"><i class="fa fa-asterisk"><span class="sr-only">This field is required</span></i> E-mail Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" 
        data-validation-engine="validate[required, custom[email], ajax[email_exists]]"
        data-errormessage-value-missing="This field is required"
        data-errormessage="Invalid E-mail address"
        value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>"
        placeholder="your@email.com">
        <span class="form-control-feedback"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></span>
        <?php echo form_error('email'); ?>
</div>
```

Here is my controller (how I'm returning a response):

**php**

```
public function ajax_email_exists() {
    if ($this->user_model->email_exists($this->input->get('fieldValue'))) {
        echo json_encode(array('email', FALSE));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('email', TRUE));
    }
}
```

When the user blurs out of the email field, I do an ajax call `email_exists` which is working fine as well. Here is what that looks like. It is located in the `jquery.validation-engine-en.js` file as suggested in the docs.

**jquery**

```
'email_exists': {
    'url': 'path-to-my-script.php',
    'alertTextLoad': '<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i> Validating, please wait...',
    'alertTextOk': '<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> E-mail address is valid',
    'alertText': '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> That Email-address already exists'
},
```

The validation itself is working great. I am getting correct response back - the problem I'm running into is I can't seem to figure out how to make the success of the ajax call to call the `onFieldSuccess` method. As soon as I blur out of the email field `onFieldFailure` is called and my input is red. When the ajax validation is complete, I am unable to get rid of the invalid style and apply my valid style. In essence, call the `onFieldSuccess` method to give the correct feedback.

A thought I had was maybe I need to look at using `funcCall` instead?
Thank you for your time & suggestions!

**EDIT**

I've updated my initialize method to add css classes to the elment(s). It seems i'm *always* getting to `addFailureCssClassToField` even when I am getting a success result back from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone come across this thread, here is how I came up with a solution.

As mentioned before, all of my validation is/was working correctly. The problem was updating the feedback accordingly. I was unable to update the style(s) to reflect what was happening.

I have updated/cleaned up the plugin code itself so my line numbers are going to be off. That said, around line #1578, you will find this:

**jquery**

```
if (options.showPrompts) {
    // see if we should display a green prompt
    if (msg) {
        methods._showPrompt(errorField, msg, "pass", true, options);
        options.onFieldSuccess(errorField); // Added this line.
    } else {
        methods._closePrompt(errorField);
    }
}
```

Because I was getting a success response, I needed to call onFieldSuccess. I am also passing in the field element (jQuery object) to render to.